# Can't call a method through broadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to call a method (postMessage) through a broadcastReceiver by Passing the context but is not working.

What is the mistake ? I tried many things but still not working.

```
 public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver implements
            OnActivityResultListener {


        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            try {
         controler(context); 

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(
                        context,
                        "There was an error somewhere",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    public void controler(Context context) {
  String radioButtonName = MAinActivity.actionAlarmName(radioButtonName);

            if (radioButtonName.equals("1")) {
        //      TODO
            } else if (radioButtonName.equals("2")) {
    postMessage(context);
    }
    }

    public void postMessage(Context context) {

            DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch (which) {
                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                        // Yes button clicked

                        break;

                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                        // No button clicked
                        break;
                    }
                }
            };
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure?")
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
                    .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show a dialog in receiver without activity context, you can you this:

```
dialog.getWindow.setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT)
```

Do not forgot add permission in AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 2):

The `Context` you receive in `onReceive()` of a `BroadcastReceiver` is not Activity Context, its application context. You can not display dialogs with application context. Dialog should always be associated with an `Activity`.

Answer (score 1):

Add your receiver in AndroidManifest

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" android:process=":remote" />
```

Comment: I did already add the receiver to the manifest file but still not working.

Comment: share your method to set the alarm.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the official documentation of Android You cannot show dialog in your on recieve method.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive(android.content.Context,android.content.Intent)

Even though you want to show a dialog then u can user an alternative approach  of starting a activity with dialog style or
you can start an transparent activity which will show the alert dialog in their on create method.

Hope this helps: